# Ошибка: Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file

Tags: java, android, android-data-binding

Т.е ошибка обозначает,что Идентификаторы должны иметь определенные пользователем типы из XML-файла. Изображениям не хватает этого файла. **Какого?**
Делаю согласно этой статьи https://habrahabr.ru/company/dataart/blog/267735/
подскажите, что я забыл подключить:
XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="click"
            type="com.retrofa.potehkilulibalse.ClickListener" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainitem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{images.isDownload ? click.onDownloadedClick : click.onClick}"/>


    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Class

```
public class Images {
    public boolean isDownload;
    public String image;


    public Images(boolean isDownload, String image) {
        this.isDownload = isDownload;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Обработчик:

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);

    void onDownloadedClick(View view);
}
```

Class:

```
public class RecyclerClickListener implements ClickListener {


    private ArrayItems mArrayItems;

    public RecyclerClickListener() {
        mArrayItems = new ArrayItems();
    }   

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadedClick(View view) {

    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
        ****/ data binding error ****
        msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file.
        images is missing it file:D:\Bo\Android project\PotehkiL\app\src\main\res\layout\item_circle.xml
        loc:23:31 - 23:36
        ****\ data binding error ****
```

Comment: В build.gradle уровня модуля в секцию `android{}` добавлено:     `dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }`

Comment: @pavlofff  да,Все добавлено

Comment: а как вы назначаете этот слушатель виджету?

Comment: @ pavlofff
как-то так
` ((ViewHolder0) holder).l.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) new RecyclerClickListener());`

Comment: прочитайте в статье, как назначается слушатель через биндинг внимательно (по имени переменной для биндинга (click) и через обращение к binding - `holder.binding.setClick()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следуя сообщению в ошибке

> "images is missing"

и посмотрев на `xml` (если это его первозданный вид, а не выжимка), то можно увидеть, что у вас класс `Images` не импортирован, следовательно биндер и не может найти переменную `isDownload`. Для решения проблемы импортируйте данный класс в `xml`.